# How can i login to a website and save cookies?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Im trying to automate a login system that i created.
I want to get the cookie after logged to use in another code.
How i get this cookies now: I manually log in to the site, get first cookie, go to the second page, to generate the second cookie.

After searching some articles here, put some codes together, with no sucess. Used fiddle to get the login parameters, that are just like this: perfil=1&txtLogin=*****&txtSenha=*****&envia=1

```
<?php
$loginUrl = 
'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp';
define('perfil', '1');
define('txtLogin', '*****');
define('txtSenha', '*****');
define('envia', '1');
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 
'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp');
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 
'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp');
$postValues = array(
'perfil' => perfil,
'txtLogin' => txtLogin,
'txtSenha' => txtSenha,
'envia' => envia
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath(COOKIE_FILE) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

echo curl_exec($curl);
?>
'
```

What i want is that this code save the cookie from this website, if possible in this format: ASPSESSIONIDSEDTDDRT=KGJKDBOCKJEIPMNCMOGFJCBD; ASPSESSIONIDSGCQADQT=GAKNEBOCNLIHEDGKNIKHECPH.
I dont know php, just read some articles here, to try to make this piece of code.

Comment: I think if the cookie is stored correctly, you can just use $_COOKIE to get it back on other sites. I think you should read up on where to save the cookie for it to be available for PHP. Maybe it is all good - I don't know.

Comment: Thats the problem, its not saving the cookie.

Comment: I don't know if you can put the cookie content into a variable but if you manage that you could just save it manually with: setcookie() - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Maybe check the object in $curl with var_dump($curl) and see if you can get the cookie or there is a method called getCookie or something. You can check that with get_class_methods(get_class($curl)) - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the cod and now i can login and save cookie to a txt file. Below the code that is working.

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp";
$referer = "...";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36";
$url_notas = "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp";
$referer_notas = "...";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'perfil=1&txtLogin=xxxxx&txtSenha=xxxxx&envia=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__). '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

print_r(curl_exec($ch));
print_r(curl_errno($ch));
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

echo "<hr>";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_notas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer_notas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie2.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__). '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

print_r(curl_exec($ch));
print_r(curl_errno($ch));
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
?>
```

Now i have other problem. When it log in it automatically shows the redirection page and stop the code. After sucessful log to https://www.https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp, it goes to https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/intro.htm, but when i run mu code it logs in and goes to https://127.0.0.1/intro.htm. How can i stop it to go to this page, so i can implement some code below it.